# "change" event listener not working for <select> element on mobile. (HTML, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, addeventlistener, onchange

I'm trying to toggle the disabled attribute of a `<select>` element if another `<select>` element has been filled out. It currently works perfectly on Computer browsers including chrome and firefox but, when I load up the website on my phone (chrome), the JavaScript just **does not** run. Here's the code I have at the moment, I would love to know what the issue might be here:

```js
// Booking and Selecting
const bookingSelectElement = document.getElementById('booking-options');
const infillSelectElement = document.getElementById('infill');
const infillOptions = document.querySelectorAll('#infill > option');

// Runs perfectly on PC. Doesn't do anything on mobile.
bookingSelectElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if(bookingSelectElement.value != "" && bookingSelectElement.value != "removal") {
        alert("Alerted on Change"); // Testing Purposes
        infillSelectElement.disabled = false; // Allows infill options to be selected
    } else {
        infillSelectElement.disabled = true; // Disabled infill options
        infillOptions[0].selected = true; // sets infill option to none
    }
})
```

```html
<label for="booking-options" class="form-label">Booking Options</label>
<select name="booking-options" id="booking-options" class="select-input split-select">
    <option value="">Select an Option</option>
    <option value="natural-classic-set">Natural Classic Set</option>
    <option value="classic-set">Classic Set</option>
    <option value="dramatic-classic-set">Dramatic Classic Set</option>
    <option value="yy-hybrid-set">YY Hybrid Set</option>
    <option value="light-volume-set">Light Volume Set</option>
    <option value="removal">Removal</option>
</select>

<label for="infill" class="form-label">Infill Type</label>
<!-- Automatically disabled until a set is selected -->
<select name="infill" id="infill" class="select-input split-select" disabled>
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="2-week">2 Week Infill</option>
    <option value="3-week">3 Week Infill</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I know often if you have a `<script>` inside `<head>` it won't be able to find elements via `document.getElementById` and friends because it [executes before the HTML elements are created](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/237955). A quick fix is to place the `<script>` tag at the bottom of your `<body>` tag. You won't know unless you [step thru the code using the JS debugger](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp) built in to your web browser.